# Why can't I access the frameworkElement's SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement

I send a FrameworkElement object through to a method in my ViewModel which is responsible for creating a new item in the TreeView.

```
public void NewFile(FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
```

When I debug, I can see what is in the frameworkElement's SelectedItem, but when I want to get hold of it, e.g.

```
frameworkElement.SelectedItem.ID
```

then I can't. Intellisense doesn't give me that option. Why not?
And then of course, how do I get hold of the SelectedItem's ID?

Comment: Because SelectedItem is not a property of the FrameworkElement class. You need to typecast it to an ItemsCollection and construct your logic so that that always works.

Comment: Thanks, your comment could have been much clearer and helpful, but I managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work as follows, based on Henk Holterman's comment:

```
System.Windows.Controls.TreeView treeView = frameworkElement as System.Windows.Controls.TreeView;

Parameter selectedParameter = treeView.SelectedItem as Parameter;
int id = selectedParameter.ID;
```